# Why data is getting entered twice database in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter.
Initially I ignored,but problem is when I click on input type submit of ask_ques data is getting enters twice in database.
user.php is model file and savedata1 method of insert.php controller is calling insertques method of model.
please help me and also explain the flaws in my programming 
Thanks in advance.

```
login_client.php

<html ">
  <head>
    <title>Simple Login with CodeIgniter</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>User Login </h1>
    <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
    <?php echo form_open('client_login'); ?>
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" size="20" id="username" name="username"/>
      <br/>
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" size="20" id="passowrd" name="password"/>
      <br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>


client_login.php

<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Client_login extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('user','',TRUE);

  }

  function index()
  { 

    //This method will have the credentials validation
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'trim|required|xss_clean|callback_check_database');

    if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
      //Field validation failed.  User redirected to login page

      $this->load->view('client_login');
    }
    else
    {
      //Go to private area

      redirect('home2', 'refresh');
    }

  }

  function check_database($password)
  {
    //Field validation succeeded.  Validate against database
    $username = $this->input->post('username');

    //query the database
    $result = $this->user->login($username, $password);

    if($result)
    {
      $sess_array = array();
      foreach($result as $row)
      {
        $sess_array = array(
          'userid' => $row->userid,
          'username' => $row->email
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata('logged_in', $sess_array);
      }
      return TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
      $this->form_validation->set_message('check_database', 'Invalid username or password');
      return false;
    }
  }
}
?>

home2.php

<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
session_start(); //we need to call PHP's session object to access it through CI
class Home2 extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();

  }

  function index()
  {
    if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
    {
      $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
       $data['userid'] = $session_data['userid'];
      $this->load->view('home_page1', $data);

     // 
    }
    else
    {
      //If no session, redirect to login page
      redirect('calllogin', 'refresh');//
    }
  }

  function logout()
  {
    $this->session->unset_userdata('logged_in');
    session_destroy();

    redirect('home2', 'refresh');
  }

   function askques()
   {
      $this->load->helper("form");
      $this->load->view('ask_ques');
   }
}

?>

calllogin.php

<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Calllogin extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();


  }

  function index()
  {

    $this->load->helper('form');
    $data["email"]="";
    $this->load->view('login_client',$data);
  }

}

?>


home_page1.php

 <?phpsession_start();  ?>
<div align="center" style="background-color: #b0c4de;height:50px">

  <h2>Welcome <?php  ?>!</h2>
<span style="color:blue;"><a href="home2/logout">Logout</a></span>
<!--<span style="color:blue">login</a></span> -->
<span style="color:blue"><input type="text" id=""style="height:30px;width:300px">search</span>
<span  style="color:blue;margin-left:50px" id="notification" >
<input type="hidden" id="h_v" value="<?php echo $userid ;?>"/>
</span>
</div>
<div align="center" style="background-color: #b0c4de;height:100px;">

 <span style="color:blue;"> <img src="<?php echo base_url('images/myimage.png');?>"   width="50" height="60">

</span>
<span  style="color:blue" id="questions"> Question&nbsp;&nbsp;

</span>
<span style="color:blue"> Tag&nbsp;&nbsp;

</span>
<span style="color:blue"> User&nbsp;&nbsp;

</span>
<span style="color:blue"> Unanswered

</span>

<span style="color:blue;margin-left:300px" > <a href="<?php echo site_url('home2/askques')?>">Askquestions</a>

</span>
</div>
<div id="title"  style="background-color: #b0c4de;height:80px;width:800px;margin-left:100px;float:left">

</div>
<div id="date" style="background-color: #b0c4de;height:80px;width:80px;float:left;margin-left:100px">

</div>
<div  id="ques" style="background-color:#b0c4de ;height:500px;width:500px;  margin-top: 100px;margin-left:100px;overflow: auto;    
    scrollbar-base-color:#ffeaff;-ms-overflow-y: hidden;">
<!--<p style="height:800px;width:600px"></p>  -->
</div>
<div id="tag" style="background-color: #b0c4de;height:50px;width:100px;  margin-top:10px;margin-left:100px;">

</div>

<div hidden  id="oldans" style="background-color:#b0c4de ;height:400px;width:600px;  margin-top: 20px;margin-left:100px;overflow: auto;    
    scrollbar-base-color:#ffeaff;-ms-overflow-y: hidden;">


</div>
<div   id="ans" style="background-color:#b0c4de ;height:400px;width:600px;  margin-top: 20px;margin-left:100px;overflow: auto;    
    scrollbar-base-color:#ffeaff;-ms-overflow-y: hidden;">
<textarea name='quesans' id='quesans' style="height:400px;width:600px;overflow: auto;    scrollbar-base-color:#ffeaff;-ms-overflow-y: hidden;" rows="80000"/></textarea>

</div>
<span id="pspan">Answer your:</span>
<span id="poans"></span>



ask_ques.php

<html>
 <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>
   <form name="" id="" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/insert/savedata1" >
<div align="center" style="background-color: #b0c4de;height:50px">
<!--<span style="color:blue;">signup</span> -->

<span style="color:blue"><input type="text" id=""style="height:30px;width:300px">&nbsp;search</span>

</div>
<div align="center" style="background-color: #b0c4de;height:100px;">

<span style="color:blue;"> <img src="<?php echo base_url('images/myimage.png');?>"   width="50" height="60">

</span>
<span style="color:blue"> Question&nbsp;&nbsp;

</span>
<span style="color:blue"> Tag&nbsp;&nbsp;

</span>
<span style="color:blue"> User&nbsp;&nbsp;

</span>
<span style="color:blue"> Unanswered

</span>

</div>
<div align="" style="background-color: #b0c4de;height:80px;width:800px;margin-left:100px;float:left">
<span style="color:blue;margin-left:100px">Title:<input type="text" name="title" id="title" style="height:30px;width:400px;"></span>
</div>
<div align="" style="background-color: #b0c4de;height:80px;width:80px;float:left;margin-left:100px">

</div>
<div align="" style="background-color: #b0c4de;height:500px;width:500px;  margin-top: 100px;margin-left:100px;">

<textarea name='comment' id='comment' style="height:500px;width:900px;overflow: auto;    scrollbar-base-color:#ffeaff;-ms-overflow-y: hidden;" rows="80000"/></textarea>
<!--<p style="height:800px;width:600px"></p>  -->
</div>
<div align="" style="background-color: #b0c4de;height:50px;width:200px;  margin-top:10px;margin-left:100px;">
Tag:<input type="text" value="" name="tag" >
<input type="submit" value="Post question" >
</div>
</form>
</html>


insert.php

<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
session_start(); //we need to call PHP's session object to access it through CI

class Insert extends CI_Controller {

  function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library("form_validation");

    $this->load->model('user');
  }

  function index()
  {     

         $title=$this->input->post("title");
         $comment=$this->input->post("comment");
         $tag=$this->input->post("tag");
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title ', 'required');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('comment', 'Question is', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('tag', 'Tag ', 'required|callback_savedata1');

        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {  

            $this->load->view('ask_ques');
        }

}


  function savedata1(){

    $title=$this->input->post("title");
    $comment=$this->input->post("comment");
    $tag=$this->input->post("tag");
    $bool=$this->user->insertques($title,$comment,$tag);

     if($bool == true){

             $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
             $data['userid'] = $session_data['userid'];
             $this->load->view('home_page1', $data);


     }
     else
        {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('savedata','please check ur question');
        //echo "hi";
        //echo 'enter unique no'; 
        return FALSE;
        }

}

         function getdata()
        {

            $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
            $data = $session_data['userid'];
            $this->user->get_ques($data);
         }
          function getalldata()
        {   

              $this->user->get_quest();
         }
         function display()
        {   

              $this->user->get_single();
         }
          function inserans()
        {   

              $this->user->set_ans();
         }

          function selectans()
        {   

              $this->user->select();
         }
          function data()
        {   

              $this->user->data();
         }

          function status()
        {   

              $this->user->gets();
         }

}

?>


user.php  // model file

<?php
//session_start(); //we need to call PHP's session object to access it through CI

Class User extends CI_Model
{           
     function login($username, $password){
        $this -> db -> select('userid,email, password');
        $this -> db -> from('clients');
        $this -> db -> where('email = ' . "'" . $username . "'"); 
        $this -> db -> where('password = ' . "'" . $password . "'"); 
        $this -> db -> limit(1);

        $query = $this -> db -> get();

        if($query -> num_rows() == 1)
        {
            return $query->result();
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }

           }

    function saveemail($email,$pass){


        $sql="INSERT INTO admin(email,password) VALUES ('$email','$pass')";
        if(mysql_query($sql))
        return true;
        else
        return false;
    }
    function savedetails($email,$pass){


        $sql="INSERT INTO clients(email,password) VALUES ('$email','$pass')";
        if(mysql_query($sql))
        return true;
        else
        return false;
    }
    function insertques($title,$comment,$tag){
       $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
       $data = $session_data['userid'];

      //echo $data+"hisd";
       $myText = (string)$comment;
      $sql="INSERT INTO Question(title,question,data,datetime,tag) VALUES ('$title','$myText','$data',NOW(),'$tag')";
      mysql_query($sql);
        if(mysql_query($sql))
        {
                        $sql= "SELECT * FROM Question  WHERE  qid=(Select MAX(qid) from question  WHERE data =$data)";
                        $recordset = mysql_query($sql);
                        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($recordset))
                           {
                             $d= $row['qid'];
                           }
                  $sql1="INSERT INTO status(qid,data,status) VALUES ('$d','$data','0')";
                     mysql_query($sql1);

        return true;
        }
        else
        return false;
    }
    function get_ques($data)//intially call
    {

        $sql= "SELECT * FROM Question  WHERE  qid=(Select MAX(qid) from question  WHERE data =$data)";

       $recordset = mysql_query($sql);
          // $data = array();
            if(mysql_num_rows($recordset) > 0)  //if record exists
            {
               while ($curr_record = mysql_fetch_assoc($recordset))
               {  
                   //$data[] = $curr_record;
                  echo json_encode($curr_record );

               }
              // echo  json_encode($data);
            }


    }
    function get_quest()
    {  
       $sql= "SELECT title,qid ,datetime FROM Question ";
        $data = array();
       $recordset = mysql_query($sql);

            if(mysql_num_rows($recordset) > 0)  //if record exists
            {
               while ($curr_record = mysql_fetch_assoc($recordset))
               {  
                  $data[] = $curr_record;
                 //echo  json_encode($curr_record);


               }
                echo  json_encode($data);

            }
            else
                  echo  json_encode($data);

    }

    function get_single()
    {    
       $id=$_REQUEST['qid'];
       $sql= "SELECT * FROM Question WHERE qid='$id' ";

       $recordset = mysql_query($sql);

            if(mysql_num_rows($recordset) > 0)  //if record exists
            {
               while ($curr_record = mysql_fetch_assoc($recordset))
               {  

                 echo  json_encode($curr_record);


               }


            }
            else
                  echo json_encode();  
    }

    function set_ans()
    {

       $id=$_REQUEST['qid'];
       $ans=$_REQUEST['ans'];
       $data=$_REQUEST['data'];
       $sql="INSERT INTO answer(qid,answer,datetime,data) VALUES ('$id','$ans',NOW(),'$data')";
       mysql_query($sql);
        if(mysql_query($sql))
        {
          $sql1="Update status set status= 1 where qid='$id'";
                     mysql_query($sql1);
        echo yes;
        }
    }

    function select()
    { 

       $id=$_REQUEST['qid'];

       $sql= "SELECT * FROM answer WHERE qid='$id' ";
        $data = array();
       $recordset = mysql_query($sql);

            if(mysql_num_rows($recordset) > 0)  //if record exists
            {
               while ($curr_record = mysql_fetch_assoc($recordset))
               {  
                   $data[] = $curr_record;



               }
               echo json_encode($data);

            }
            else
              echo "no";

    }

    function data()
    { 

       $id=$_REQUEST['qid'];
       $sql= "SELECT * FROM question WHERE qid='$id' ";
       $data = array();
       $recordset = mysql_query($sql);

            if(mysql_num_rows($recordset) > 0)  //if record exists
            {
               while ($curr_record = mysql_fetch_assoc($recordset))
               {  
                   $data[] = $curr_record;



               }
               echo json_encode($data);

            }
            else
              echo "no";

    }
    function gets()
    { 

       $id=$_REQUEST['data'];
       $s=1;
       $sql= "SELECT * FROM status WHERE data='$id' and status='$s'";
       $data = array();
       $recordset = mysql_query($sql);

            if(mysql_num_rows($recordset) > 0)  //if record exists
            {
               while ($curr_record = mysql_fetch_assoc($recordset))
               {  
                   $data[] = $curr_record;



               }
               echo json_encode($data);

            }
            else
              echo "no";

    }


}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is right here:

```
mysql_query($sql);
        if(mysql_query($sql))
        {
                        $sql= "SELECT * FROM Question  WHERE  qid=(Select MAX(qid) from question  WHERE data =$data)";
                        $recordset = mysql_query($sql);
                        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($recordset))
                           {
                             $d= $row['qid'];
                           }
                  $sql1="INSERT INTO status(qid,data,status) VALUES ('$d','$data','0')";
                     mysql_query($sql1);

        return true;
        }
        else
        return false;
```

Remember, the code inside the if() is being executed - so you are running the INSERT statement on the first line, and then accidentally running it a second time on the if(mysql_query($sql)) line.  Just remove the first mysql_query line and you should be okay (although mysql_query itself is very outdated and shouldn't be used).

Comment: hey great answer man. Thanks lot for patiently working on my code and what should i use instead of  mysql_query.Please explain other flaws if possible